# Integral domain in a commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So I have a question where I'm not sure what assumptions I can make.

Here are the conclusions and information about the problem from previous parts of the question that I've completed.

$R$ is a commutative ring with unit. $R = (R,+_R,0_R,*_R,1_R) $
Let the set $S:= R\times R$ and give it the following two operations.

1. $(a_1,b_1)+_S(a_2,b_2) := (a_1 +_R a_2, b_1 +_R b_2)$.
2. $(a_1,b_1)*_S (a_2,b_2):= (a_1 *_R a_2, a_1 *_R b_2 +_R a_2 *_R b_1)$.

I've proven that:

- $*_S$ is associative.
- $S$ with the two operators is a commutative ring.

Where I'm having trouble is in this:

> Let $(0,b)\in S$. Compute $(0,b)^2$. Is S an integral domain?

Am I correct in thinking that $(0,b)^2 = (0,b)*_S(0,b)$

I tried expanding this into:

$$(0,b)*_S (0,b)=(0*_R0,0*_Rb+_R0*_Rb)$$
$$=(0*_R0,b*_R(0+_R0)).$$

I'm confused if $(0*_R0=0)$ and $(0+_R0=0)$ since it's $0$ and not $0_R$.

What would be the way forward from here?

Also how can I use this to show if $S$ is an integral domain?

I'm new to abstract algebra so any help is appreciated.

Comment: They just write $0$ rather than $0_B$ because there is no other zero it could be in tje context and it gets tedious to have so many subscripts everywhere. Once you do the computation, the answer to whether this is an integral (!) domain should be clear from the definition.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Don't you mean $0_S$ or $0_R$?

Comment: Right, sorry. Misread the symbol.

Comment: So would $0_S$ and $0_R$ be the same then such that $0_S *_R 0_S = 0_S$

Comment: No, those are elements of different rings so they are not equal. And you cannot use the multiplication from one ring on the elements of the other.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So if they meant $0_S$ how would I do the computation? I also just noticed that since $S:=R \times R$ would that mean the two identities are similar? Trying to research a bit on direct product of rings to check this.

Comment: Actually I think I misunderstood, I think it should be $0_R$ they are referring to since in $(a,b)$ the $a$ comes from the first ring in the direct product and the $b$ comes from the second which in this case are the same. I'll see how I get on with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I got with the help of @TobiasKildetoft in the comments was that when they stated $(0,b)$ they meant $(0_R,b)$ for simplicity.
This means the computation becomes trivial and I find
$$(0_R,b)^2 = (0_R,0_R)$$

The definition of integral domain states there are no non-zero zero divisors.
Thus since $(0,b)$ is a non-zero element in $S$ and $(0,b)(0,b) = 0$, then S cannot be an integral domain.